# Pop from stash without indexing changes

Tags: git, githooks, lint, git-stash

*Context:*

I want to run rubocop in a git pre-commit hook, but I assuming I have a stashed change that would cause it to complain, and an unstashed change that somehow fixes this, the offending change would slip by rubocop.

*My solution so far:*

Before running rubocop, run `git stash --keep-index -u` to stash all unstaged changes before running rubocop

*The problem:*

After running rubocop, `git stash pop` restores the working tree to its previous state, but stages all those changes (which were previously unstaged)

*My question:*

Is there an option to pop the stash without automatically staging any of the popped changes?

*or*

Is there some other way to run a program on the project as it would be committed, instead of the working tree with possible unstaged changes?

---

To reproduce the situation:

```sh
# Set up a dummy repo
  git init
  echo foo > file
  git add foo && git commit -m "Initial"
# Make a change and stage it
  echo bar >> file
  git add file
# Make another change and *don't* stage it
  echo baz >> file
# This is what I later want to restore:
  git status && git diff && git diff --cached
# Stash only unstaged changes (and ignored / untracked files)
  git stash --keep-index -u
# So far everything is as it should be
  git status && git diff && git diff --cached
# Run whatever script on the code
  rubocop .
# This is where things go wrong though:
  git stash pop
# Both changes are now staged to be committed 
  git status && git diff && git diff --cached
```

Comment: @RomainValeri A typo indeed! Fixed it, thanks for letting me know :D

Comment: Writing a good pre-commit script is harder than one might think, because of the fact that Git commits from the index. Or rather, from *an* index, which may or may not be *the* index (`git commit --only` vs `git commit --include`). Using `git stash --keep-index` doesn't really get you where you want in all cases. I haven't actually gone and tested this method, but I think the "right" way to test a proposed commit is to use `git  checkout-index` to copy the proposed commit to a separate testing area, test it there, and use that result (and never try to update index or work-tree locally).

Comment: If you're determined to keep working with `git stash`, though, remember to use `git stash pop --index` at the end, so as to keep the distinction between index copy and work-tree copy. Note that you'll have to reset the work-tree first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an option to pop the stash without automatically staging any of the popped changes?

Not an option, no, but you can get that effect yourself with

```
index=`git write-tree`
git stash pop
git read-tree $index
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `git write-tree` thing was exactly the hint I needed to make it work :D